# Cambiar STATUS PHP para recogerlo desde Unity

Tags: php, http, unity

Tengo un fichero en `php` donde recibo unos datos desde una aplicación en Unity,
todo bien hasta que tras validar la informacion necesito recuperar un `STATUS`.

Estoy empleando esta forma de setear el `STATUS` en `php`;

```
if(count(mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($sqlSelectNombUser,$cone)))>1){

$result="no valido";
http_response_code(400);

}else{

 $result="valido";
 $rsInsertNew=mysql_query($sqlInsertNew,$cone);
 http_response_code(200);

}
```

Y para recuperarlo desde Unity utilizo;

```
public static int getResponseCode(WWW request)
{
    int ret = 0;

    if (request.responseHeaders == null)
    {
        Debug.LogError("no response headers.");
    }
    else
    {

        if (!request.responseHeaders.ContainsKey("STATUS"))
        {
            Debug.LogError("response headers has no STATUS.");
        }
        else
        {
            ret = parseResponseCode(request.responseHeaders["STATUS"]);
        }
    }

    return ret;
}

public static int parseResponseCode(string statusLine)
{
    int ret = 0;

    string[] components = statusLine.Split(' ');
    if (components.Length < 3)
    {
        Debug.LogError("invalid response status: " + statusLine);
    }
    else
    {
        if (!int.TryParse(components[1], out ret))
        {
            Debug.LogError("invalid response code: " + components[1]);
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

El caso es que no consigo cambiar `STATUS`ya que siempre recibo el 200, aun habiendo forzado el fallo directamente en el `PHP`.

¿Cómo podría cambiar el `STATUS`para recuperarlo en Unity?

Comment: Yo lo que suelo hacer es que la respuesta sea a través de un JSON, entonces al recibir la respuesta de los post, convierto mi respuesta de php a json y valido con los códigos propios...

Comment: @Calleth'Zion' podrias proporcionar un ejemplo? entiendo que si lo realizas por `JSON` (cuerpo), harias un `POST`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizo esta libreria Json para facilitar mi trabajo: SimpleJSON:
[Librería JSON para Unity](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON)

Y el ejemplo de uso sería:

En el botón o lugar donde mandarías llamar:

```
StartCoroutine (iniPost ());
```

Y para hacer el post:

```
IEnumerator iniPost (){ 
    // Creamos la forma para hacer el post
    var form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField ("categoria", "1");//Agregamos variables necesarias
    var url = "http://direccionalPost.com/test.php";
    var d = new WWW( url, form );
    // Llamamos método para escuchar la respuesta del post
    StartCoroutine(WaitForRequest(d));
    if(d == null)
        yield return null;
}
```

Para escuchar la respuesta:

```
IEnumerator WaitForRequest(WWW www){
    yield return www;
    // buscamos errores
    if (www.error == null){//No hubo error en el post
        Debug.Log( "Json " + www.text );
        au = JSON.Parse (www.text);//Convertimos la respuesta a Json con la librería SimpleJson, hacer el import con el Using SimpleJSON;
        if (au ["error"] != null && au ["error"].ToString ().Length > 0) {//Localmente validadmos que no se haya enviado error nuestro, en caso de que exista la llave lo imprimimos

            Debug.Log ( au ["error"]);
        } else {
            Debug.Log ("No hubo error buscamos llaves necesarias");

        }
    } else {
        Debug.Log ("Error en el post: " + www.error);
    }    
}
```

Lo que debes tú responder en tu php cuando haya error sería:

```
{"error":"No valido", "status_code":"400"}
```

Cuando no haya error:

```
{"status_code":"200"}
```

Y ya sería de tu parte agregar las demás cosas que necesites...